# How to find truly NEW apps on the Play store?

Tags: google-play-games

How can I find new apps on the Play store?  It seems that everything that is returned is just the popular stuff all the time.  I'm interested in locating and trying out new apps (mostly games) outside of the popular stuff.

When looking at the "new and recently updated" that always is flooded with the popular apps that are at the top of the charts already that I've seen a million times.

Answer (score 1):

[Appbrain](http://www.appbrain.com), considered front end of Google Play does that. You can filter apps by various criteria as shown for example for*games → Action→ New*

[image]
[image][image]