# See all Reviews/AppRatings on PlayStore in a better Way?

Tags: google-play-store

Is there a better way to see all Reviews / Ratings with Comments on an Android App in the Play Store?

Right now i on a Android Device, i can scroll to infinity and in the Browser i only get some random 40 reviews. Sometimes (on the Android Play Store) it also resets my settings for the filter.

---

### Update

For better understanding, i want to read all comments programmatic and store them in a database for further analytics.

So the best thing would be something like a WebAPI or a Website which provide an tabular overview of all comments/reviews.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Play Store reviews , IMO , are not a good indicator of an app for reasons mentioned [Why You Shouldn't Trust App Store Reviews (and What to Trust Instead)](http://lifehacker.com/why-you-shouldnt-trust-app-store-reviews-and-what-to-1515379780).

- [Appbrain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps&hl=en) a front end for Google Play , gives a better filtering capability as mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/154091/131553). In addition, you do get a better insight of app in terms of rating over time, updating details, change in price, versions etc

[image]
[image]
[image]

- [Aptoide](http://m.aptoide.com/) , at least an alternative of *numerically* showing the number of reviewers per rating , along with overall rating and use that in addition to alternate ways suggested . Screen shot below

[image]

---

Post your update in the question, [Sensor Tower](https://sensortower.com/) could be an option. It is a paid service but offers a flavour of services by free login for [Facebook](https://sensortower.com/ios/us/facebook-inc/app/facebook/284882215/#) for example

Amongst the host of features it offers, [Review History](http://help.sensortower.com/article/126-review-history) is one of them as shown below

[image]

> Export Reviews (Enterprise-only)- Export of reviews in .csv format will not be displayed unless you are logged in with an Enterprise-level account.

Answer (score 2):

In the Play Store at your choosen app press the "Read all reviews" button, now you have to access all reviews (Only on your language. I am not sure you can read reviews around worldwide, but I guess you are'nt interested chinese ones anyways.) You should scroll all the way down to reveal all of the reviews.

Comment: On which device? can you please provide a screenshot? i can't find this button.

Comment: Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro with CM13 (6.0.1). 
You can see screenshots here: [link](http://imgur.com/a/jXk8v)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list of reviews by "Only newest" and "only for your device".
This is done in Google Play Store with the DropDown on the right top, when you hit a review (and thus open all reviews list).

Also you can sort the list by useful reviews, rating and newest review.

Comment: Yeah! but this is a bad method because it shows you sometimes multiply data and has always to load reviews at the bottom of the list.