# View all app ratings/reviews in one place irrespective of language

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have been using Google Play and Google Play Developer Console for monitoring the status and ratings/reviews for my apps on Google Play.

One thing I have observed is that, we can *only* view some the ratings and reviews in our current locale (language) on the Developer Console. If a user rates my app, say in Spanish or Portuguese, I am not able to see that rating anywhere (neither on Google Play nor on the developer console). Only, if such a person also writes a review, would I be able to see it on the Developer console.

One way out of this, is to individually append the hl-(locale code) say, *hl-es* or *hl-fr* on the URL of the page on Google Play. But this is tedious as I have to guess which locale the current user who just rated my app (and didn't put a review) is from.

I can also download the ratings from the console in .csv format, but this is never up-to-date.

Any solutions, to view all ratings and reviews from all languages, in one place?

Comment: Related https://android.stackexchange.com/q/154589/131553

Comment: @beeshyams They are talking only about reviews, not about pure ratings without reviews :)