# Download all Reviews/App-Rattings from a App on Google PlayStore

Tags: google-play-store, python

I'm searching for a way to download all Ratings with Comments from an App on Google Play Store.
The best way would be to do this directly in python.

I have tried to download the whole website with the python package request. It works but load only about 140 - 160 Rattings with comments.
On the website, there is a way to click the button "see all comments". But then i must scroll to infinity. That is not the way I am searching for.

For clearness I want the data for a private NLP Projekt, so I don't have my own App.
Therfore all ways with the Developer Console not possbile for me.

The question is related to this one: [See all Reviews/AppRatings on PlayStore in a better Way?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154589/see-all-reviews-appratings-on-playstore-in-a-better-way)
But the ways don't work anymore or I have no developer acces.

Comment: Have you tried python modules like `google-play-scraper`? They claim to be able to download app reviews.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the hint. The google-play-scraper was exactly the tool i was searching for.